# syntax error throwing up while comparing in python

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

I have the following code

```
n = int(input())
s = set(map(int, input().split()))
N= int(input())

for i in range(1,N+1):
    ops=input()
    li=ops.split(' ')

    if li[0]=='pop':
        s.pop()
    elif li[0]=='discard':

        s.discard(int(li[1])
    elif li[0]=='remove':
       if (li[1]) in s:
            s.remove((li[1])


print(sum(s))
```

here I tried comparing the string I have in the li[0] with 'remove' but it throws an syntax error:

```
$python3 main.py
  File "main.py", line 14
    elif li[0]=='remove':
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am unable to find out where am I going wrong. Can you figure it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the line above, and below, print misses the closing `)`

```
print(1)
```

And

```
print(2)
```

---

*update*

Also your new code misses a `)`, twice

```
s.discard(int(li[1]))
```

And, here's actually a `(` too many

```
s.remove(li[1])
```

Comment: Same with print(2)

Comment: Yeah.. I get that.. My Bad :|